Running Docker on AlmaLinux with csf firewall (or any firewall script)
I have recently learned a piece of software I use has upgraded to Docker. I asked a devop to install it and they said docker doesn’t work with csf iptables firewall. It goes without saying, I need that. I just wondered if this is true, or can a second network be used for docker containers?
Help solve my sanity!
The program is RhodeCode CE and is developed for docker now
AlmaLinux release 8.10 (Cerulean Leopard)
Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb
csf: v14.22 (generic)


The devops person bent the truth. Docker definitely can work with csf iptables rule, although it is a little tricky. Maybe I'll figure it out for you and write an asnwer.

Found a solution to your problem!; check my answer ;)

When Docker runs, it creates its own set of iptables rules to manage container networking, without consulting other firewall tools like CSF. This can then cause conflicts. (This is probably why the devops person bent the truth- to avoid hassle.)
But there is actually a Docker chain designed to combat this issue, called DOCKER-USER. Rules you add to this chain are processed before Docker’s own rules, which means that Docker won't override them.
This is all explained in the official Docker docs I linked above.
For example, if you want to allow traffic from a specific IP to containers, you can use DOCKER-USER to override Docker.
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT


This StackOverflow question has more information on the matter as well, if you need.

you can use DOCKER-USER You can even avoid using CSF whatsoever as well. It doesn't mean that the devops person bent the truth though. Besides, what if CSF whatsoever insert/prepend DROP rules instead?

@TomYan sorry, please could you clarify what you ate stating/asking? Yes you can avoid anything on choice, but the OP wants to use CSF, as they say. And if it’s what you’re asking, yes DOCKER-USER works with DROP rules as well. I can add that.

So Docker can "slot into place" with CSF by simply using DOCKER-USER somehow? and if so, how would you do that? With CSF all you do is modify csf.conf to open ports etc etc. Are you saying there is a work around for use with Docker?

@youdsmedia You can edit the csfpost.sh file and put any iptables rules you like in (with DOCKER-USER, of course!)

OK, so, I'm not sure I 100% follow this. I would put iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT into csfpost.sh for the IP of the container so docker can do its thing?

I am a bit confused… in whatever file you edit, don’t you just add in the iptables-like rules? (E.g. they’re the same format as iptables like my example.

No, you never use iptables rules, only edit a .conf file for opening ports and so on.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
